# Calculate LoRa message length with code rate

Tags: rate, parity, lora

I'm looking for a formula, with that I can calculate the message length of my payload that is sent over the Lora modulation.

Example:

```
message length without parity bits: 8 bits,
coding rate: 4/5
```

Is there a formula to calculate the message length with the added parity bits?

Comment: seems to me that when you don't add parity bits then there aren't parity bits. Also I think that a code rate of 4/5 is too little of information. Do you have anything like the lorawan datarate/spreading factor?